# Teamcity 9.1 server shutdown

Tags: teamcity

i was just trying out TeamCity, but it looks like i have a problem. When I start the server, it runs for about minute or two, and then it shuts down. Everytime. I have looked in logs, but found nothing useful.. Any ideas on where the problem could be?
Thanks

```
INFO: Server startup in 11259 ms
TeamCity version: 9.1 (build 36973), data format version 727
OS: Linux, User: root, JRE: 1.7.0_79-b14 OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
JVM parameters: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/TeamCity/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=270m -Dteamcity.configuration.path=../conf/teamcity-startup.properties -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/var/TeamCity/bin/../conf/teamcity-server-log4j.xml -Dteamcity_logs=../logs/ -Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/var/TeamCity/endorsed -Dcatalina.base=/var/TeamCity -Dcatalina.home=/var/TeamCity -Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/TeamCity/temp
=======================================================================
TeamCity initialized, server UUID: da891db9-fabd-4aae-9bc6-c645ba47af0f
TeamCity is running in professional mode
Super user authentication token: "1207310690207057748". To login as Super user use an empty username and this token as a password on the login page.
Killed
```

Answer (score 1):

I think TeamCity is trying to update its references to TC 9.1 and needs the token from the log file which you have posted.

If you open TeamCity on your browser and then paste the token "1207310690207057748" with an empty username, you will then be redirected to a maintenance page which will give you more info of what exactly is happening.

I can see that the process is killed at the end, I am assuming that this is done by you by either using -Kill processId or ./teamcity.sh stop force ?

Let me know if the 1st suggestion works.

Cheers,
Vishal

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by changing "shutdown" port (/conf/server.xml). Something was killing my server process on the default one.